# sbt submit gives "not a valid command" error

Tags: scala, sbt

Trying to submit my assignments. Looks easy from the demo, but receiving weird error. SBT version is correct. What may be wrong?

```
> sbt-version
[info] 0.12.4
> submit
[error] Not a valid command: submit (similar: set)
[error] Expected '/'
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: submit
```

Comment: as i remember you should also provide your mail with a special key, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be using the code package for the course downloaded from the Coursera course web site, otherwise there will be no `submit` command available as it's not a built-in of SBT or Scala or anything. This is also covered by the tutorial video lecture, and you will be able to obtain the link from the course site.

Also, you need to provide your e-mail address and submission key (which you can obtain from the course web site) as parameters to the `submit` command.

Comment: yes, I watched all the videos... but imported the example incorrectly :) thanks.

Comment: How do you use the code package? Is it defined in the build.sbt page?

Answer (score 2):

> yes, I watched all the videos... but imported the example incorrectly :)

To correctly import the example, you need to ***run `sbt` in the folder with the `build.sbt` file***. In my case, [the `scalatest` version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12/3.2.0-SNAP10) was not found. To fix, it could be updated to (in `CommonBuild.scala`):

```
lazy val scalaTestDependency = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0-SNAP10" % Test
```